# Unable to run a simple karma test against my angular 4 code

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-mocha, angular2-testing, karma-coverage

I'm trying to do a bare minimum test on my Angular 4 components, and I can't get it to work at all.

I'm running this command: `karma start src/test/javascript/karma.conf.js`

And here is the output:  `Error: This test module uses the component AppComponent which is using a "templateUrl" or "styleUrls", but they were never compiled. Please call "TestBed.compileComponents" before your test.`

Here is my app.component.spec.ts file:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import  {AppComponent} from "../../../../../main/webapp/app/admin/app";

describe('AppComponent (minimal)', () => {
    it('should create', () => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ AppComponent ]
        })
            .compileComponents();

        const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        const component = fixture.componentInstance;
        expect(component).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

And I just want  to test out some of the functions I created in that app.component.ts file, and maybe test some of the HTTML in app.component.html

And here is my karma.conf.js file:

```
const webpackConfig = require('../../../webpack/webpack.test.js');

const ChromiumRevision = require('puppeteer/package.json').puppeteer.chromium_revision;
const Downloader = require('puppeteer/utils/ChromiumDownloader');
const revisionInfo = Downloader.revisionInfo(Downloader.currentPlatform(), ChromiumRevision);
process.env.CHROMIUM_BIN = revisionInfo.executablePath;

const WATCH = process.argv.indexOf('--watch') > -1;

module.exports = (config) => {
    config.set({

        // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
        basePath: './',

        // frameworks to use
        // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
        frameworks: ['jasmine', 'intl-shim'],

        // plugins
        plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-junit-reporter'),
            require('karma-notify-reporter'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-remap-istanbul'),
            require('karma-sonarqube-reporter'),
            require('karma-webpack'),
            require('karma-sourcemap-loader'),
            require("karma-intl-shim")
        ],

        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            'spec/entry.ts'
        ],


        // list of files to exclude
        exclude: ['e2e/**'],

        // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
        // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
        preprocessors: {
            'spec/entry.ts': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
        },

        webpack: webpackConfig(WATCH),

        // test results reporter to use
        // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
        // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
        reporters: ['dots', 'junit', 'progress', 'karma-remap-istanbul', 'notify', 'sonarqube'],

        junitReporter: {
            outputFile: '../../../../target/test-results/karma/TESTS-results.xml'
        },

        notifyReporter: {
            reportEachFailure: true, // Default: false, will notify on every failed sepc
            reportSuccess: true // Default: true, will notify when a suite was successful
        },


        remapIstanbulReporter: {
            reports: { // eslint-disable-line
                'lcovonly': 'target/test-results/coverage/report-lcov/lcov.info',
                'html': 'target/test-results/coverage',
                'text-summary': null
            }
        },

        sonarqubeReporter: {
            //basePath: 'src/app',        // test files folder
            basePath: './',             // test files folder
            filePattern: '**/*spec.ts', // test files glob pattern
            encoding: 'utf-8',          // test files encoding
            outputFolder: 'target/test-results/karma',    // report destination - target/test-results/karma
            legacyMode: false,          // report for Sonarqube < 6.2 (disabled)
            reportName: 'karma-sonarqube-report.xml'
        },

        // web server port
        port: 9876,

        // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors: true,

        // level of logging
        // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch: WATCH,

        // start these browsers
        // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
        browsers: ['ChromiumHeadlessNoSandbox'],

        customLaunchers: {
            ChromiumHeadlessNoSandbox: {
                base: 'ChromiumHeadless',
                flags: ['--no-sandbox']
            }
        },

        // Ensure all browsers can run tests written in .ts files
        mime: {
            'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
        },

        // Continuous Integration mode
        // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
        singleRun: !WATCH
    });
};
```

---

edit: when I try it with this code:

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
    let component: AppComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ AppComponent]
        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

I still get the same error, and here is a bit more of my stacktrace:

```
  Error: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load %3Cdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ch2%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%3EApplication%20Management%3C/span%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cbutton%.....(lots and lots of "HTML" here)
            at resolvePromise (http://localhost:9877webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:783:0 <- spec/entry.ts:93156:31)
            at resolvePromise (http://localhost:9877webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:754:0 <- spec/entry.ts:93127:17)
            at http://localhost:9877webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:831:0 <- spec/entry.ts:93204:17
            at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:9877webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:0 <- spec/entry.ts:92797:31)
            ...

        Error: This test module uses the component AppComponent which is using a "templateUrl" or "styleUrls", but they were never compiled. Please call "TestBed.compileComponents" before your test.
            at TestBed._initIfNeeded (http://localhost:9877webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js:756:0 <- spec/entry.ts:36698:27)
            at TestBed.createComponent (http://localhost:9877webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js:873:0 <- spec/entry.ts:36815:14)
            at Function.TestBed.createComponent (http://localhost:9877webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js:652:0 <- spec/entry.ts:36594:29)
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9877webpack:///src/test/javascript/spec/app/admin/app.component.spec.ts:16:26 <- spec/entry.ts:80888:37)
            ...

        Expected undefined to be truthy.
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9877webpack:///src/test/javascript/spec/app/admin/app.component.spec.ts:22:26 <- spec/entry.ts:80893:27)
```

I do see this talks about my entry.ts, which is here:

```
TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting());

declare let require: any;
const testsContext: any = require.context('./', true, /\.spec/);
testsContext.keys().forEach(testsContext);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { UiTestModule } from '../../../test.module';
import {AccountService, Principal} from "../../../../../../main/webapp/app/shared";
import {DashboardService} from "../../../../../../main/webapp/app/dashboard/dashboard.service";
import {AppService} from "../../../../../../main/webapp/app/admin/app";
import {JhiEventManager, JhiParseLinks} from "ng-jhipster";
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from "@angular/router";
import {ToasterAlertService} from "../../../../../../main/webapp/app/shared/alert/toaster-alert.service";
import {ToastOptions, ToastsManager} from "ng2-toastr";
import { AppComponent} from "../../../../../../main/webapp/app/admin/app";
import {DomSanitizer} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

describe('AppComponent', () => {

    let comp: AppComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
    // let service: JhiHealthService;

    const fakeActivatedRoute = {
        snapshot: { data: { } },
    } as ActivatedRoute;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [UiTestModule],
            declarations: [AppComponent],
            providers: [
                AppService,
                JhiParseLinks,
                Principal,
                {
                    provide: ActivatedRoute,
                    useValue: {
                        data: {
                            // subscribe: (fn: (value: Data) => void) => fn({
                            subscribe: (fn: () => void) => fn({
                                // company: COMPANY,
                                pagingParams:  {
                                    page: 1
                                }
                            }),
                        },
                        params: {
                            // subscribe: (fn: (value: Params) => void) => fn({
                            subscribe: (fn: () => void) => fn({
                                tab: 0,
                            }),
                        },
                        snapshot: {
                            url: [
                                {
                                    path: 'foo',
                                },
                                {
                                    path: 'bar',
                                },
                                {
                                    path: 'baz',
                                },
                            ],
                        },
                    },
                },
                { provide: Router, useValue: null },
                JhiEventManager,
                DomSanitizer,
                ToasterAlertService,

                AccountService,
                ToastsManager,
                ToastOptions
            ]
        }).overrideTemplate(AppComponent, '')
        .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;
        // service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(JhiHealthService);
    });

    describe('TODO3', () => {
        it('TODO4', () => {
            expect(comp.foo()).toEqual('bar');

        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The Test Bed is usually called and components/fixtures are initialized *before* each test and not within each test (usually).

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AppComponent]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: I just edited my post (see "edit: when I try it with this code:"). I'm using your code but still gets the same error